# Count the number of instances of a string of text in an entire dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, count

I have a dataframe and I want to count the number of instances of a particular string of text.

For example in the below dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- iris %>%
  distinct(Species) %>%
  mutate(Species2 = Species,
         Species3 = Species)
df
#      Species   Species2   Species3
# 1     setosa     setosa     setosa
# 2 versicolor versicolor versicolor
# 3  virginica  virginica  virginica
```

I want to count the number of times "setosa" occurs

Using `length(grep("setosa", df$Species))` I can get the counts of setosa in a specific column but how can I do this to the whole dataframe?

I tried `length(grep("setosa", df))` which comes back as zero.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the iris dataset a good example for your question? It has only one column that contains words, but from your question, it sounds like you are interested in a situation where there are several columns with words and maybe also sentences or longer sequences of words/characters that might contain the target string? Otherwise `dplyr::count(iris, Species)` should do the trick.

Comment: @Till i second that

Comment: In the example there are 3 columns that contain words, I want to look at the entire dataframe and count how many instances of "setosa" occurs.

Comment: Why not just `sum(df == "setosa")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want total count, rather than count by column, your code works if you convert the dataframe to a matrix first:

```r
length(grep("setosa", as.matrix(df)))
```

which returns 3.

Note: unlike `unlist()` this also works when columns have different classes:

```r
length(grep("OJ", as.matrix(ToothGrowth)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the count of exact matches, all you need is simply

```r
sum(df == "setosa")
```

---

In a more general case that `grep()` or `stringr::str_count()` is necessary, e.g. there are sentences that might contain the target string, you can use `Reduce()` to sum up the count of each column iteratively.

```r
Reduce(\(x, y) x + sum(grepl("setosa", y)), df, init = 0)
```

---

##### Benchmark on a larger dataset

It shows that the simplest way performs the best. In the general case, my approach takes almost the same time as others', but uses much less amount of allocated memory.

```r
# Dimension: 10000 x 100
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), 1e6, replace = TRUE), 1e4, 1e2))

bench::mark(
  exact_match = sum(df == "setosa"),
  Darren = Reduce(\(x, y) x + sum(grepl("setosa", y)), df, init = 0),
  nrennie = length(grep("setosa", as.matrix(df))),
  jkatam = sum(sapply(df, \(x) grepl('setosa', x))),
  iterations = 100
)

# # A tibble: 4 × 13
#   expression       min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result
#   <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>
# 1 exact_match     17ms  17.8ms     55.4    11.53MB   35.4      61    39       1.1s <int> 
# 2 Darren         232ms 247.1ms      4.01    3.86MB    0.446    90    10      22.4s <dbl> 
# 3 nrennie        240ms 255.7ms      3.91   12.79MB    1.30     75    25      19.2s <int> 
# 4 jkatam         239ms 253.2ms      3.94   11.46MB    2.32     63    37        16s <int>
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = sample(c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  var2 = sample(c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  var3 = sample(c("setosa", "virginica", "versicolor"), 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

You can either use `table()` to get counts for each word in the dataset.

```r
unlist(df) |> 
  table()
#> 
#>     setosa versicolor  virginica 
#>        108        104         88
```

Or filter down (`purrr::keep()`) to only include occurences of “setosa”
and then get the count with `length()`.

```r
df |> 
  unlist() |> 
  keep(\(x) x == "setosa") |> 
  length()
#> [1] 108
```

Comment: You'd need to check all columns were characters first. If you have columns with different classes then `unlist()` doesn't work. See `unlist(ToothGrowth)` - the `supp` column disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with `sapply` as below

```r
df2 <- sum(sapply(df, \(x) grepl('setosa', x)))
```

Answer (score -2):

For example -To count the instances of B:M you could use str_count in the stringr library in combination with sum():

```
sum(stringr::str_count(df$overlaps, "B:M"))
```